# making entire div clickable with a link

Tags: css

Let me just say before I ask this question ..I did try searching for a long time through existing topics but I can't find a working solution to my problem.

I am using Bootstrap and have a horizontal list of items with icons and a text link underneath. What I want is basically the entire div clickable as the link, not just the actual text.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="glyphs character-mapping">
                <li>
                  <div data-icon="a" class="icon"></div>
                  <a href="">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div data-icon="b" class="icon"></div>
                  <a href="">Link 2</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.glyphs.character-mapping {

margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #000000;

}
.glyphs.character-mapping li {

margin: 0px 10px 30px;
display: inline-block;
width: 165px;
text-align: center;

}
.glyphs.character-mapping .icon {

margin: 10px 0px 10px 45px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
color: #FF0000;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 68px; 

}
```

I tried several solutions that are related on here, including giving no padding or margin to the 'li' and instead making the 'a' 100% wide and high, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not wrap the link around the div?

Comment: I've given you an answer @user3708727. Any chance you can give feedback/accept if it was helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
<ul class="glyphs character-mapping">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <div data-icon="a" class="icon"></div>
            Link 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <div data-icon="b" class="icon"></div>
            Link 2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where the entire div and text is clickable?

Comment: Correct, this is now possible. At some point it wasn't valid HTML (before 4.0 I think) but it is now.